# How to not let google map group addresses together?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

i am using google map api to show addresses on map with markers, the problem i am having is, In the marker, i am showing a link to go to the profile page of person which is there in the map, but if there are more than 1 person exists on same address then google group those addresses and doesn't show the link, is there any way we can stop grouping of addresses? 
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
var global =0;
//<![CDATA[
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
  var side_bar_html = "";
  var gmarkers = [];
  var htmls = [];
  var i = 0;

  var allIcon = new GIcon();
  allIcon.image = "images/icons/<?php echo $map_category; ?>-all.png";
  allIcon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
  allIcon.iconSize = new GSize(35, 29);
  allIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
  allIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);
  allIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2);
  allIcon.infoShadowAnchor = new GPoint(18, 25);
  allIcon.transparent = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/markerTransparent.png";
  allIcon.printImage = "coldmarkerie.gif";
  allIcon.mozPrintImage = "coldmarkerff.gif";

  // An array of GIcons, to make the selection easier
  var icons = [];
  icons[0] = allIcon;
  icons[1] = planIcon;
  icons[2] = specialIcon;

  var clusterIcon = new GIcon();
  clusterIcon.image = 'images/icons/<?php echo $map_category; ?>-all.png';
  clusterIcon.iconSize = new GSize( 30, 51 );
  clusterIcon.shadowSize = new GSize( 56, 51 );
  clusterIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint( 13, 34 );
  clusterIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint( 13, 3 );
  clusterIcon.infoShadowAnchor = new GPoint( 27, 37 );


  // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
  function createMarker(point,name,html,cat,id) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point,icons[cat]);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    rating_html = CallRating(<?php echo $page_id; ?>,id);
    rating_html = decodeURI(rating_html);
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);        
    document.getElementById("rating_html_"+id+"").innerHTML=rating_html;
    });
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragstart", function() {
      map.closeInfoWindow();
    });
    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers[i] = marker;
    htmls[i] = html;
    // add a line to the side_bar html
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        var sclass="even";
    }
    else
    {
        var sclass="odd";
    }
    side_bar_html += '<li class="'+sclass+'"><a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ',' + id + ')" class="map_data mapdata-list">' + name + '<\/a></li>';
    global=i;
    i++;
    return marker;
  }

  // This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
  function myclick(i,id) {
    rating_html = CallRating(<?php echo $page_id; ?>,id);
    rating_html = decodeURI(rating_html);
    gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);           
    document.getElementById("rating_html_"+id+"").innerHTML=rating_html;
  }


  // create the map
  var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  //map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $emp_info['emp_latitude']; ?>, <?php echo $emp_info['emp_longitude']; ?>), 8);
  // create the clusterer
  var clusterer = new Clusterer(map);

  // set the clusterer parameters if you dont like the defaults
  clusterer.icon = clusterIcon;      
  clusterer.maxVisibleMarkers = 100;
  clusterer.gridSize = 5;
  clusterer.minMarkersPerClusterer = 5;
  clusterer.maxLinesPerInfoBox = 6;

  var rating_html="";   
  // Read the data 
  var request = GXmlHttp.create();
  request.open("GET", "xml/<?php echo $org_id.'/emp/'.$emp_id.'/'.$map_category; ?>.xml", true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(request.responseText);
      // obtain the array of markers and loop through it
      var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      var i = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        // obtain the attribues of each marker
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
        var point = new GPoint(lng,lat);
        var town = markers[i].getAttribute("town");
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
        var cat = markers[i].getAttribute("cat");
        var marker = createMarker(point,name,"<a href='<?php echo $url;?>="+id+"' target='_blank' class='map_data'>"+name+"</a><br>"+town+"<div id='rating_html_"+id+"'></div>",cat,id);
        // create clusterer object
        clusterer.AddMarker(marker,town);
      }
      // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
      if(side_bar_html=="")
      {
        document.getElementById("list_html").innerHTML = "<li>No data found! Please try again.</li>";
      } 
      else
      {
          document.getElementById("list_html").innerHTML = side_bar_html; 
          gmarkers[global].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[global]);
          map.closeInfoWindow();
      }   
      // Clear the "please wait" message
    }
  }
  request.send(null);
}

else {
  alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
}

//]]>
</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: i have posted the code, please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good thing that google is showing all the relative address together otherwise if it wont, markers will be hidden by each other and you wont be able to see even how many markers are there on one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you put multiple markers for single `point`, those will always overlap. It will be interesting to see if anyone can help you. I would suggest, when there are more than one people come under same place/marker, put their details/links on the `infoWindow`. Don't try to show multiple markers for same point. And if you are desperate enough to show multiple markers, then just change size of your marker-icons, so that they are visible to user even-if overlaps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is not that markers are overlapping, the problem is that when i am calling the createMarker function and the markers are being created on the map, then what happening is it is showing details of everyone who has the same address in just one info window, like if there are 10 persons addresses on same place, then it is doing like this :
1st person name
2nd person name
3rd person name
4th person name
5th person name
 & 5 more......

This is what is happening and they are not links, which is causing the problem.